# Java http cookie

Tags: java, http, cookies

How can i get the cookie contents from a URL in java ?

Eg: Using LiveHttpHeaders when i visit google.com i can see cookie returned as follows.

Cookie: **SID**=`DQAAAKEAAADA1VJiGC-O-Ml8cPfRIA8NxJ3rCQfXbRnh5NMw-l8eunfAKJNypj9Rss1_Ok2yyQXCU9qu4jM2TuASy2EE0KUknUOsdOgMz3W7WCDgey6OSZ-xi_ozh_lZP8paJ_OViG_G2FaTWciTyd4Mp_V0LYjgov1u6KkhATu8day8-nEckMXb4I56cse8SaiYFCjDmpUDmL6CDFij8Nxd3XDUEOTn5SCifKrRDohW6mAAaqzFPA; HSID=AvoV_TPUEmoSB6KMm; PREF=ID=260f8c0212fee1a7:U=6ca9509bc747fb21:TM=1297164689:LM=1297164690:S=opeCe3s85Xhm3Bq1; NID=43=EZNhkfgLmXVNQriZ2rjU0HGj6flDYy2nfsPD4Ef6pME0wvXxc5_avP1R9fSea0py_-F9xY3SJ6DpMvLXRT_bU7FH97s8sOmx7l49cwvNUbYTwJcY0xqs-0vKqybTeNZY`

How do i get the value of SID ? These things are not available in `getHeaderFieldKey()` of UrlConnection class. I tried to get the default cookieHandler but the system returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp");
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
```

Since a server may set multiple cookies in a single request, we will need to loop through the response headers, looking for all headers named "Set-Cookie".

```
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
    String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);               
    ...
```

**Extract cookie name and value from cookie string**:

The string returned by the `getHeaderField(int index)` method is a series of `name=value` separated by `semi-colons (;)`. The first name/value pairing is actual data string you are interested in (i.e. `"sessionId=0949eeee22222rtg" or "userId=igbrown"`), the subsequent name/value pairings are meta-information can be used to manage the storage of the cookie (when it expires, etc.).

```
 cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
    String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
    String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to set the cookie handler *before* you connect to the url (e.g. `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager())`).  then the cookies will be collected automagically and you can retrieve them from the CookieHandler if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.getCookies()` where request is of type `HttpServletRequest`. Request is passed to method `doGet` and/or `doPost` that your are expected to implement in servlet or JSP body if you are using JSP.